# How to read pig output in separate Java program

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have some pig output files and want to read them on another machine(without hadoop installation). I just want to read a tab-seperated plain text line and parse it into a java object. I am guessing we should be able to use pig.jar as dependency and be able to read it. I could not find relevant documentation. I think [this](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html) class could be used? How can we provide the schema also.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to store data in Avro serialization format. It is Pig-independent and it allows to handle complex data structures like you described (so you don't need to write your own parser). See [this article](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/07/04/using-avro-in-mapreduce-jobs-with-hadoop-pig-hive/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your pig output files are just text files, right? Then you don't need any pig or hadoop jars.
Last time i worked with Pig was on amazon's EMR platform, and the output files were stashed in an s3 bucket. They were just text files and standard java can read the file in.

That class you referenced is for reading into pig from some text format.

Are you asking for a library to parse the pig data model into java objects?  I.e. the text representation of tuples & bags, etc? If so then its probably easier to write it yourself. It's a VERY simple data model with only 3 -ish datatypes..

Comment: My file also contains bags and maps, do i have to write a parser for that? For example this schema is difficult to parse 

A = LOAD 'mydata' AS (T1:tuple(f1:int, f2:int), B:bag{T2:tuple(t1:float,t2:float)}, M:map[] );

I guess the pig library is parsing them into a java object right?

Comment: I'm not sure if you could reuse the Pig api external to Hadoop or not. Sorry. I just realised that the schema for your Pig data is potentially dynamic, and so any parser you implement would have to be fairly 'clever'.